# android - my app not showing in the list of default app selection popup?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a music player app in android studio. When I run it, there is no issue and the app is running well but when I try to play a song from file manager, my app not showing in the app selection popup. How can I display my app in default app selection popup?

Comment: Do your app captures the intent?

Comment: @Fustigador I think, Not. How to do it?

Comment: Refer to the page @nejc92 linked, and find out. And if it does not answer your question, search about intent filters in google.

Comment: Thanks @Fustigador. It worked.

Comment: Thanks @nejc92. It worked but the song is not playing when i select my player. Any help?

Comment: @ParagKadam Which one manifest or java code?